# Deletar todas as palavras depois de um caractere específico

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Gostaria de deletar todas as palavras, caracteres e espaços que aparecem depois da barra (/) em um dataframe pandas, porém não sei como fazer.
Eu usei este código para substituir erros em vogais em meu df, porém não sei como faria para deletar tudo depois da barra:

```
df1.replace({"a'":"à", "e'":"è", "i'":"ì", "o'":"ò", "u'":"ù", "/n"}, regex=True)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para deletar tudo depois da barra (/) em um dataframe pandas, você pode usar a função str.split junto com a função apply para dividir a string em duas partes, a primeira parte antes da barra e a segunda depois da barra. Em seguida, você pode usar a função lambda para selecionar apenas a primeira parte da string dividida e atribuir o resultado à mesma coluna do dataframe original.

Por exemplo, suponha que você tenha um dataframe df com uma coluna chamada coluna e que deseja deletar tudo depois da barra (/) nessa coluna. Você pode fazer isso da seguinte maneira:

```
df['coluna'] = df['coluna'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0])
```

Isso dividirá cada string da coluna coluna em duas partes, a primeira parte antes da barra e a segunda depois da barra, e atribuirá apenas a primeira parte à mesma coluna do dataframe original.

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Antonioli. Funcionou.